# How do I read from file and print one byte at a time? Then remove the spaces and puctuations. Then store the words in a character array

Tags: c, for-loop, byte, punctuation

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>       
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WM 15


int main()                 {
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,n, counter2, counter1, low, high, mid;

char sort, dummy, quit;
int a, GotBack, count, Got, innerCount;
bool DEBUG;
char temp[WM]; 
a = 0;
char* line[a][255];
char* search[a];
char* words[a];
long filelen;
char *buffer;
int buff;

FILE* Cprograms;

Cprograms = fopen("finalread.c", "r");

printf("Words in from the paragarph:"); 


    fseek(Cprograms, 0, SEEK_END);          
    filelen = ftell(Cprograms);            
    rewind(Cprograms);                      
    buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char)); 

    for(i = 0; i < filelen; i++) {
       
       fread(buffer+i, 1, 1, Cprograms); 
    
     }


     

    printf("File len: %d\n", filelen);
    printf("%s\n",*&buffer);
   

fclose(Cprograms); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Words in from the paragarph:File len: 559
To be, or not to be, that is the question:
Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles
And by opposing end them. To die, to sleep,
No more; and by a sleep to say we end
The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks
That flesh is heir to: 'tis a consummation
Devoutly to be wish'd. To die, to sleep;
To sleep, perchance to dream, ay, there's the rub:
For in that sleep of death what dreams may come,
When we have shuffled off this mortal coil,
Must give us pause☻☺♥►☻☺♥ ☻☺♥ ☻←┌yç╧‼
```

I want the code to read only one byte at a time. Then I need the code to split the one-byte buffer into words and remove punctuation and make them lowercase and store them. Like char *words[] = { "to", "be", "or" }. I want it in a loop so each time it reads one byte does everything and goes back to start again.

For example,
if this stored in the file
"To be, or not to be, that is the question:"
I'll need the code to first read "To Be, or" which is a byte
Then print "To Be, or"
Then remover spaces and puctuations and divde them by words and make them lower case like
"to", "be", "or.
Then store them in an array.
Then goes back to read "not to be,"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jaya! As currently phrased, this question isn't clear enough for folks to help. Please clearly describe the problem you're trying to solve -- just describing the desired output for one input isn't a clear specification. Also, it would be good to know where you're stuck in the problem in front of you, and what you've tried.

Comment: You're asking how to split the buffer into words? But, before that, I notice that you're printing garbage chars at the end. That's because `fread` does _not_ terminate with the EOS char (0x00). So, after the loop, do: `buffer[filelen] = 0;`. And, to simplify: change `printf("%s\n",*&buffer);` into `printf("%s\n",buffer);` Also, since you're reading one char at a time, you could use `fgetc` instead of `fread`.

Comment: As to the split, please edit your _question_ and add additional info on _how_ you want to split. You said: `To be, or not to be, that is the question:` needs to split into `To Be, or`? I _think_ you just want to split on whitespace, lowercase the words, removing punctuation (e.g `,` or `.` or `:`)? So, the output should be an array dynamically created that is the equivalent of this: `char *words[] = { "to", "be", "or", "not", "to", "be", "that", "is", "the", "question", NULL };`? That is a literal conversion with duplicates. Or, do you want a "dictionary" with just _unique_ words?

Comment: _Side note:_ Your input file [containing the phrases] is `finalread.c`. Doable, but a bit confusing because `.c` is the extension for C source code, and usually _not_ for input data. I'd change that to (e.g.) `input.txt` or `data.txt` or `raw.txt`, ...